# Blender - Export to DAE with texture

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, export

Okay, i have a really wierd problem. I am totally new to blender, and i have just bought a 3D model of a present, to play a little around with.

The 3D model looks very nice, and in Rendered, Material and texture mode are all the materials showing perfectly fine (not in Solid though, the present is just gray here).

So... Now i want to make this file into a .dae-file, so that i can use it in Xcode. And here comes the problem. "The model export, but not the texture." And i dont want a totally gray present in my app. ;)

I have nothing done with the present (nothing else than pay $ for it). I go into: Export -> Collada (.dae) and have the Texture options like this:

[image]

(I have also tried the other options)

The blender file looks like this in blender.

[image]

But the .dae-file look like this.
[image]
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: How is the last picture taken? Maybe, if it wasn't blender, the problem is on the other side; in your Xcode/App that isn't able to display the materials.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that link has nothing to do with Blender being unable exporting textures with dae or obj - the texture option COPY is checked yet it does not help with Blender v3.6.4. It looks more like another Blender export bug.